# Wowza Streaming Engine stopped and it does not start anymore

Tags: wowza

Everything was working but suddenly Wowza Streaming Engine stopped and it does not start anymore. I tried start it using services.msc as a admin but it was useless too.

Wowza Streaming Engine Manager is working.

Wowza version: 4.1.0
Windows 8

Comment: Try running startup.bat in `%WMS_HOME%/bin` directory. Also share logs from `%WMS_HOME%/logs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice hint ikikenis.

I saw the logs and it showed that my free license key was expired. I got another one and put it on the %WMS_HOME%/conf/Server.license.

Everything is working fine now. Thanks